# Please tell me how to put Excel data in several model columns

Tags: python, django, excel, django-import-export

.Hello~ I am studying using django, I am getting some help because there is a blockage, I am currently practicing to upload an Excel file as Django data. But, the problem is that I have no idea what to do when there are data related to multiple models in one Excel file, so I am asking for help.

Currently, there are Questions model and Choice model Voters model. The Choice model refers to Question and Voters models as ForeignKeys.
Additionally, the data of all current models is empty, and the data value in Excel becomes the initial value.

And it may be difficult to understand
The primary_key (identifier) ​​of Questions is Question_text
Choice's primary_key (identifier) ​​is Choice_text,
Voters' primary_key (identifier) ​​is voters_name .
Therefore, Question_text and Voters_nm in Excel are both identifiers and duplicate data.

I have been asking this problem on Stack Overflow for a few days and reading the official documents of django-excel and django-import-export several times, but nothing is solved... If you have a similar experience, please give me an answer.

If you need an example, I will provide an example as well.

Originally, it was a much more complicated example, but if it gets too complicated, I feel like I'm asking for everything, so this is a simplified question as much as possible... Thank you for reading this long post.

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(primary_key=True,max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True,
                            default="question")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    voters_name = models.ForeignKey('Voters', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    choice_text = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text


class Voters(models.Model):
    voters_name = models.CharField(primary_key=True,max_length=100)
    voters_number = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    
    def  __str__(self):
        return self.voters_name
```

is csv

```
Question_text,Publish Date,Question,Voters_Nm,voters_nm,Choice,Noise,Votes
What is your favourite programming language?,2004-01-15,language,kim,010-1234-5678,Java,1,1
What is your favourite programming language?,2004-01-15,language,hong,010-3333-1111,C++,1,1
What is your favourite programming language?,2004-01-15,language,jung,010-7777-1111,C,1,1
What is your favourite IDE?,2029-01-15,ide,kim,010-1234-5678,Eclipse,1,1
What is your favourite IDE?,2029-01-15,ide,houg,010-3333-1111,Visual Studio,1,1
What is your favourite IDE?,2029-01-15,ide,jung,010-7777-1111,PyCharm,1,1
What is your favourite IDE?,2029-01-15,ide,min,010-0000-1234,IntelliJ,1,1
```

this is git sample https://github.com/pointsiga1/django_sample.git

excel img [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQuBQ.jpg)

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Django, but I noticed a few things in the sample git files. First, it uses sqlite3 for database, not xlsx. So there's that. Second, if you want to work strictly with xlsx, then I assume you'd have to include it in your code, which I don't see. If you want, I can show you a few examples on how to use xlsx, but then again, it won't be like in the sample you shared since it uses sqlite3.

Comment: I'll use mysql when I'm done. Excel can be handled very easily, but it must be implemented on the web. All I need is how to implement and cope with logic. Please teach me the way.

Answer (score 0):

Using `django-import-export`, you can reference a FK resource like `question__slug`.

First of all, create a [resource](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#creating-import-export-resource) which maps your import fields to your model.

```py
class ChoiceResource(resources.ModelResource):

    question_text = fields.Field(
        attribute="question__question_text",
        column_name="question_text",
        widget=widgets.CharWidget(),
    )
    pub_date = fields.Field(
        attribute="question__pub_date",
        column_name="Publish Date",
        widget=widgets.DateTimeWidget(),
    )
    # Add remaining fields

    class Meta:
        model = Choice
```

Review the [widgets](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_widgets.html), and ensure you set the correct one for your import data type.

Note that if you need to follow a FK reference, you can do so with:

```py
    # note you have two columns with this name - you may need to fix that
    voters_name = fields.Field(
        attribute="Voters__voters_name",
        column_name="Voters_Nm",
        widget=widgets.CharWidget(),
    )
```

Next you should register the resource with the Django's [Admin site](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#admin-integration).  This will make it easier to test.  You can select your import XLS file, and import directly.  If you've set everything up correctly, it should work fine.

- I strongly recommend setting up a debugger so that you can step through the import process.  This will make it a lot easier to identify flaws.
- I recommend to install the `django-import-export` [example application](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#example-app) so that you can get that running and see how it should fit together.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The text was long, so I left it as text as an answer.